# Java mail sender is not working correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

The problem I've got, is that when I call `multipart.addBodyPart(msgbodypart);` it says,  I should change type of `msgbodypart` to `MimeBodyPart` at `BodyPart msgbodypart = new MimeBodyPart();`  and `msgbodypart = new MimeBodyPart();`

Okay, I change it,then it drops warning:

> The method addBodyPart(BodyPart) in the type Multipart is not applicable for the arguments (MimeBodyPart)

what now?

```
try {
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    msg.setSubject("Test Java Sending Zip File");
    msg.setText("This is a message from a java program");

    BodyPart msgbodypart = new MimeBodyPart();

    msgbodypart.setText("this is msg Body");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    msgbodypart = new MimeBodyPart();

    String filename = "zips.txt";

    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    msgbodypart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    msg.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(msgbodypart);
    msg.setContent(multipart);

    System.out.println("Sending");
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Sent!");
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to check your imports. Make sure they are all from `javax.mail...` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used older lib. JavaMail API 1.4 has this option

Answer (score 0):

```
final Session connection = Session.getInstance(props, null);
final Message message = new MimeMessage(connection);
final BodyPart bodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
final BodyPart bodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
final Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
connection.setDebug(true);
try {
    final Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(
    "RECEIVER-EMAIL-ADDRESS");
    final Address fromAddress = new InternetAddress(senderUserName);
    final String content = "Please check your attachments for a zip file";

    message.setSubject("Test Java Sending Zip File");

    bodyPart1.setText(content);
    DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource("D:\\Data.zip");
    bodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
    bodyPart2.setFileName(dataSource.getName());

    multiPart.addBodyPart(bodyPart1);
    multiPart.addBodyPart(bodyPart2);
    message.setContent(multiPart);

    message.setFrom(fromAddress);
    message.setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    Transport transport = connection.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(smtpServer, senderUserName, senderPassword);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    System.out.println("DONE !");
} catch (AddressException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```